# HYPERLINK can't find long links even when shortened by Bitly

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

With Excel VBA I use Bitly API to shorten long links. The macro ran perfectly and I was able to convert all the long links into short ones. Now, when I copy/paste these links to browser, they work fine, example `http://bit.ly/1FVcuRx` but when I use them with:

```
 =HYPERLINK(A1, 2)
```

where A1 = `http://bit.ly/1FVcuRx`, and then I click on it, it errors: "cannot find [some file, local directory]".

I am not sure how can I make it work, as the link works fine but the hyperlink doesn't work with it.

Also, I noticed one thing, for the shorter links (less than 255 characters), when I ran macro, the Bitly link works fine with HYPERLINK function.

Comment: Using Excel 2013 on Windows 7, the formula works just fine for me.

Comment: I am using 2016. with windows 8.1 . I dont have excel 2013. is there any way i can test it. Also, did you click on the cell where =hyperlink("link",1) is? Did it take you to the browser?

Comment: If you replace cell A1 with http://google.com, does it function fine? If so, do you have any web-proxy or network monitoring tool that might be an issue?

Comment: yes, it works fine with google.com or other shorter links. I am wondering is it because, the the bitly link( that I posted above) was formed from link >500 characters?

Comment: I think something's going on with the browser. Can you default your browser to firefox, chrome and IE and check if this issue can be isolated to only a specific browser? Then, just copy the text http://bit.ly/1FVcuRx and paste it in your current default browser and see if that works.

Comment: So, I tried it on chrome and IE, it worked fine. But when I click it from Excel, it doesnt work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91630/discussion-between-zedfoxus-and-user1631306).

Comment: Its seems like there are issue with excel 2013 and excel 2016( from office 365). I tried it with google docs and excel 2013 (regular edition) and it worked fine.

Comment: I have tested your code ~=HYPERLINK(A1, 2) ~ on my Office 365 and it works fine. It takes to url<http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=(%22benzo(a)pyrene%22[tiab]%20OR%20%2250-32-8%22[rn]%20OR%20%22b(a)p%22[tiab]%20OR%20%22benzo(d,%20e,%20f)chrysene%22[tiab]%20OR%20%223,4-benzopyrene%22[tiab]%20OR%20%223,4-benzo(a)pyrene%22[tiab]%20OR%20%226,7-benzopyrene%22[tiab]%20OR%20%22benz(a)pyrene%22[tiab]%20OR%20%221,2-benzpyrene%22[tiab]%20OR%20%223,4-benzp........> Please see my sample file <https://www.dropbox.com/s/06qq5p0dtnj9pdf/test_0910_2015.xlsx?dl=0>

Comment: I have excel 2016 from office 365

Comment: Then it seems something is wrong with my edition. I downloaded your file and still I got the same error. My friend tried with his 2016 office 365 and he was able to click it, but the link got truncated and he got wrong results on NCBI site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like there are issue with excel 2013 and excel 2016( from office 365). I tried it with google docs and excel 2013 (regular edition) and it worked fine.

Comment: Great find. Thank you for publishing your findings. If you can, please feel free to mark your answer as accepted to give closure to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code ~=HYPERLINK(A1, 2) ~ works fine on my excel 2016 from Office 365.
Alternatively you can turn these tiny urls to clickable hyperlinks with the following code. I have uploaded a sample file to dropbox also.https://www.dropbox.com/s/52vl33rma7468no/test_0910_2015b.xlsm?dl=0

```
Sub ConvertToHyperlinks()
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim WorkRng As Range
  On Error Resume Next
  Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
  Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
  For Each Rng In WorkRng
    Application.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Rng, Rng.Value
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: something is wrong with my excel version. When i downloaded your file and click on the hyperlinks and link, it goes to "file:///C:/Users/arpit/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/IE/5G5BWT56/pubmed%5B1%5D.htm" . Does it ring any bell? Instead of going to actual link, it goes to some local file? Its the same problem i had earlier

Comment: Excel 2013 and later version 2016 should be installed after removing previous versions of Office. I have seen conflict issues reported in various forums.

Comment: I am using window 8.1 . I am not sure if its excel issue. I tried in my frnds laptops having 2013 edition and windows 10, it had same issue. But frnds with windows 7 with excel 2013 edition, it worked fine there.

Comment: Please raise this issue in ms community forum for better resolution of the problem.